# Pentaho data integration JSON input in transformation job not showing all json objects

Tags: etl, pentaho, transformation, data-processing, pdi

I am working with Pentaho Data integration tool for some of the ETL processing jobs.

My data input is a json file named data.json having many json objects as follows:

```
{"id":"333","name":"iit"}
{"id":"444","name":"nit"}
{"id":"555","name":"iiit"}
{"id":"666","name":"jnit"}
```

and when i am using json input in the PDI transformation design, the json preview shows only first row. Please check this screenshot[image]

But the same works fine when i modify my data.json file as follows:

```
{
    "data" : [
                {"id":"333","name":"iit"},
                {"id":"444","name":"nit"},
                {"id":"555","name":"iiit"},
                {"id":"666","name":"jnit"}
            ]
}
```

Please check the screenshot for that here:
[image]

Please help out how can i fetch all the json objects present in the data.json file using the following format:

```
{"id":"333","name":"iit"}
{"id":"444","name":"nit"}
{"id":"555","name":"iiit"}
{"id":"666","name":"jnit"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your path of $.id and $.name are fine. The problem is with the JSON.

```
{"id":"333","name":"iit"}
{"id":"444","name":"nit"}
{"id":"555","name":"iiit"}
{"id":"666","name":"jnit"}
```

This is not valid JSON, and that's why only the first row gets read in. It reads that first line and then it encounters a second open curly bracket without hitting a comma and it just stops because it doesn't know what to do with invalid JSON.

Format your JSON like this and it should work with no modifications to your JSONPath.

```
{"id":"333","name":"iit"},
{"id":"444","name":"nit"},
{"id":"555","name":"iiit"},
{"id":"666","name":"jnit"}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your JSON-file looks like that, there could be done a workaround:

Create a text-file-input which reads every line and send the lines to the JSON-input.

Every line will then be considered as its own JSON-input.

[image: input steps]

You can then use the JSON-node as you intend to (if I understand you correctly)

[image: JSON input-step]

Your output will then look something like this:

[image: Results]

Use a 'select values' node to remove the json-column.

Answer (score 0):

XPath:

$.data[*].id

Is different than:

$.data

Try using $..id, and $..name, Should work on both cases and bring you all objects.